# How to export telerik report explicitly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I want to export telerik report from the Report Viewer explicitly, when I click on the link 'export', using my own method to export to Excel due to performance issues. Does anyone have Idea on, In which event should I call my ExportToExcel() method?

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to explicitly call "ExportToExcel()" method in your report you must call when the report is fully rendered. I don't think there is an event which will be fired but you can create on which should that all ExpandCollapse setting are expanded and all the Visibility/Display property to set to true. You can also look for PageSettings to see if there is anything you would want explicitly set before calling "ExportToExcel()"